# llamar a funcion php desde javascript

Tags: php, javascript

buenas tardes amigos tengo un problema que me rompe la cabeza y no logro solucionar tengo este codigo

```
function llenar_tabla_json(){
    $('.cargando').hide();
    $(".table-carrito tbody").empty();
    $("#carrito_ventas .table tbody").html("");
    $.post("comprobantes/listado_carrito",{accion:''},function(data){
        var tabla = ""; var i=1; var total = 0;
        if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data) == false){
            $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                tabla += '<tr>'
                        +'<td class="text-center">'+i+'</td>'
                        +'<td class="text-center">'
                        +'<input type="number" class="cantidad" min="1" value="'+val['cantidad']+'" data-item="'+val['id']+'|'+val['precio']+'|'+val['unidad']+'|'+val['nombre']+'|'+val['codigo_servicio']+'" style="width:50px;height:25px;text-align: center;padding: 0;">'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td class="text-center">'+val['codigo_servicio']+'</td>' 
                        +'<td class="text-center">'+val['unidad']+'</td>'
                        +'<td class="text-center">'+val['nombre']+'</td>'
                        +'<td class="text-center">'
                        +'<input type="number" step="any" class="precios" value="'+val['precio']+'" data-item="'+val['id']+'|'+val['cantidad']+'|'+val['unidad']+'|'+val['nombre']+'|'+val['codigo_servicio']+'" style="width:60px;height:25px;text-align: center;padding: 0;">'
                        +'</td>'                    
                        +'<td class="text-center">'+(val['precio'] * val['cantidad']).toFixed(2)+'</td>'
                        +'<td class="text-center">'
                        +'<a href="comprobantes/unset_producto"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'+
                        +'</td>'                  
                        +'</tr>';
                i++;
                total += (val['precio'] * val['cantidad']);
            });
            $("#carrito_ventas .table > tbody > tr").remove();
            $(".table-carrito tbody").append(tabla);
        }else{
            tabla = '<tr>'
                        +'<td class="text-center text-danger" colspan="6">'
                            +'Agregue items para empezar'
                        +'</td>'
                    +'</tr>';
            $(".table-carrito tbody").append(tabla); 
        }`
```

Quiero enviar el numero de item para elimnar del carrito de compras a esta funcion

La direccion es `comprobantes/unset_producto` y debo agregarle la variable `i`

```
public function unset_producto($unique_id)
    {
        unset($_SESSION["carrito_v"][$unique_id]);

    }
```

Comment: Creo que tienes que hacer otro `$.post` anidado en el que tienes

Comment: +'<a href="comprobantes/unset_producto"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'+ al enviar asi ya que solo llamo a la funcion pero no le agrego la variable me vota error quiero poder enviar esa variable "i"

Comment: Puedes mandarla por GET asi: `+'<a href="comprobantes/unset_producto?id='+i+'"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'+`

Comment: ya intente de esa forma y no funciona http://localhost:82/mvc/comprobantes/unset_producto?id=1

Comment: Como recibes el parametro en el archivo `unset_producto`?

Comment: lo envio directamente a la funcion public function unset_producto($unique_id)
    {
        unset($_SESSION["carrito_v"][$unique_id]);

    }

Comment: Como lo envias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al ver que ya estas usando jquery, pues lo podrias hacer de la siguiente manera:

en esta linea:

```
+'<a href="comprobantes/unset_producto"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'+
```

agregale el atributo data-id_item y la clase "btn_delete_item", para que quede asi:

```
+'<a href="comprobantes/unset_producto" class="btn_delete_item" data-id_item="'+val['id']+'"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'+
```

y esta parte fuera de tu función "llenar_tabla_json"

```
$(".table-carrito").on("click", ".btn_delete_item", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: btn.attr('href'),
        type: "GET",  //GET si el backend recibe los datos por URL o POST si los recibe con el método literal "POST"
        dataType: "json",
        data: {unique_id: btn.data('id_item')}
    })
    .done(function(data){
        alert(data.status);
    });
});
```

y el código PHP quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

public function unset_producto($unique_id){
    //al ver que la recibes como argumento entonces diría que mandas 
    //la clave por la url, aquí depende mucho de como este construido tu backend 
    //para ver como recibes los datos y ver como las vas a mandar con AJAX

    unset($_SESSION["carrito_v"][$unique_id]);
    echo json_encode(["status" => "El producto con clave " . $unique_id . " ha sido borrado"]);
}
```

Espero y te sea útil esta pequeña ayuda :)

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Comprobantes::unset_producto(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\aplication\Bootstrap.php on line 94 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\controllers\comprobantes.php:1023
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\aplication\Bootstrap.php(94): Comprobantes-&gt;unset_producto()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\aplication\Bootstrap.php(24): Bootstrap-&gt;callControllerMethod()

Comment: utilizo un framework mvc estoy empezando con esto y no se como explicarlo :(

Comment: Que framework es el que utilizas y que version??